# Using JSF, PrimeFaces and JPA: Create Basic WebApp without using Generated CRUD Classes, Forms, etc

Tags: java, jpa, jsf, primefaces

I am trying to build a basic CRUD application with NetBeans 7.4, JSF, PrimeFaces and JPA using MySQL.

**I have successfully done this by using the NetBeans wizards. I want to do this from scratch, no wizards.**

There seems to be a lack of support for the combo of JSF, PrimeFaces and JPA. When I say "lack", I mean a full example (I might be asking too much), without using the CRUD auto-gen templates/classes AND shows actual queries coded and passed to the datatables(primefaces). YouTube is full of non-English speaking examples using Hibernate (not JPA) and other examples that show flashy GUI's with no code.

So far I understand you need an @Entity class (provides the physical build of the tables), a Controller (serializable) and the .xhtml web page to show the datatable.. what else? Also, I'm not seeing any posts or examples where queries are using with JPA/JSF and how they are tied together (in one place). I need to connect the dots here so that I can leverage JSF/JPA to create simple queries to populate my PF DataTables. I've read the blogs and I've googled the intranets until I'm blue in the face. Sending me a list of URL's to read to learn about each product is something I've already done. I get what they do independently, but am looking for the "How do they all connect" answer with maybe some basic code examples!! :)

Comment: BalusC has a [really simple CRUD example](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2010/06/benefits-and-pitfalls-of-viewscoped.html) using plain JSF 2. IMO this is a good start point with 0 GUI's, just self-explained code. With this as base, you can add the database access you want/need: plain JDBC, Hibernate, JPA, MyBatis, etc.

Comment: Also, PrimeFaces is not necessary to accomplish the CRUD functionality, note that it is great to enhance the application GUI and convert a plain web application into a RIA.

Comment: Thanks. I'll review and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Since version 11, PrimeFaces comes with a `JpaLazyDataModel` which you can use with your `p:dataTable`. In its simplest form to be used like:

```java
new JpaLazyDataModel<>(MyEntity.class, () -> entityManager);
```

See also:

- [`DataTable` documentation on `JpaLazyDataModel`](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/12_0_0/#/components/datatable?id=jpalazydatamodel)
- [Source code](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/12.0.0/primefaces/src/main/java/org/primefaces/model/JpaLazyDataModel.java)

Answer (score -1):

I think this should help you:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_tutorial.pdf

Tung

Comment: Anyone have a good JPA example? I think I need to piece together how JPA fits with the beans / entities and how custom queries are used. Again, I'd like to stick with JPA, but if someone thinks that I should NOT use JPA I'm all ears! (ideally b/c it's easier and more robust) I'm looking for best practice from an enterprise point of view. I would rather take more time learning JPA if it's "better" than just using JDBC or Hibernate..

Comment: You have to start trying something on your own. I think you should read the answer of this post because it helped me once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455475/jta-mysql-how-to-retrieve-records-from-database

Answer (score -1):

look.If you need an example about CRUD operation using JPA/EJB as Model layer and JSF as view layer,you can see the follwing example:

http://uaihebert.com/?p=834

also my own blog is based on many examples explaining this.These examples are using JPA2/EJB3 as model and JSF2 and primfaces as view you can see

http://jsfspotlight.blogspot.com/2013/05/jsf2ejb3-preparing-your-environment.html (this post for explaining how to prepare your environment before developing EJB/JSF Applications

http://jsfspotlight.blogspot.com/2013/05/ejbjsf-master-detail-web-application-in_25.html
(in this post i explain in details how to create EJB/JSF master_detail Application including what you need about connecting model and view layers)

explore the blog for more examples

Answer (score -1):

Try this archetype which will create you an example and then check how it is implemented: https://github.com/ignl/happyfacescrud. You will learn about Spring, Spring security, Spring WS, JPA and Hibernate, Spring data and QueryDsl for easier querying, and custom JSF components which will make you very productive jsf developer.